# Log4j2 - writing to specific logger declared in XML

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to configure Log4j2 for few hours, but cannot solve this.

I want to use two separate loggers in my app (each class can use both of them). One logger will act similar to deafult (log somewhere) but second will collect only some of data.

Right now I have somethink like that:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

...

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ProductAttributesVerifier.class);
private static final Logger validationLoger = LogManager.getLogger("validation");

...

logger.warn("Started validation (in basic logger)");
validationLoger.info("INF Started validation of \"" + product.name + "\"");
validationLoger.warn("WRN Started validation of \"" + product.name + "\"");
validationLoger.error("ERR Started validation of \"" + product.name + "\"");
```

Content from `validationLogger` has to go to another file (where stuff from `logger` cannot appear.

My log4j2.xml (it's in root of project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="validation" fileName="validation.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="validation" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="validation"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Unfortunately file 'validation.log' doesn't appear and all logs are printed into console. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

Logs from `<Configuration level="trace">`:

```
2019-06-10 14:36:48,507 main DEBUG Apache Log4j Core 2.11.2 initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=...................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml]
2019-06-10 14:36:48,514 main DEBUG Installed 1 script engine
2019-06-10 14:36:48,808 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_201, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
2019-06-10 14:36:48,809 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 117 plugins
2019-06-10 14:36:48,809 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2019-06-10 14:36:48,813 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2019-06-10 14:36:48,815 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,825 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,826 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2019-06-10 14:36:48,840 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(..................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2019-06-10 14:36:48,840 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 47 plugins
2019-06-10 14:36:48,841 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,850 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="Console", Configuration(......................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2019-06-10 14:36:48,852 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2019-06-10 14:36:48,853 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,854 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(.............................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2019-06-10 14:36:48,870 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,873 main DEBUG FileAppender$Builder(fileName="validation.log", append="null", locking="null", advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n), name="validation", Configuration(..................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Filter=null, ={})
2019-06-10 14:36:48,875 main DEBUG Starting FileManager validation.log
2019-06-10 14:36:48,877 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,878 main DEBUG createAppenders(={Console, validation})
2019-06-10 14:36:48,879 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,883 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="validation", level="null", Filter=null)
2019-06-10 14:36:48,883 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,886 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="WARN", name="validation", includeLocation="null", ={validation}, ={}, Configuration (..........................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2019-06-10 14:36:48,888 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,889 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
2019-06-10 14:36:48,889 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,891 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", includeLocation="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(.........................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2019-06-10 14:36:48,891 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2019-06-10 14:36:48,892 main DEBUG createLoggers(={validation, root})
2019-06-10 14:36:48,892 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=.......................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml] initialized
2019-06-10 14:36:48,893 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=.......................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml]
2019-06-10 14:36:48,893 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=.......................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml] OK.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,893 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@60215eee...
2019-06-10 14:36:48,894 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,894 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,894 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,894 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,895 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2019-06-10 14:36:48,895 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2019-06-10 14:36:48,895 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2019-06-10 14:36:48,895 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,896 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,896 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@60215eee OK
2019-06-10 14:36:48,942 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@707194ba
2019-06-10 14:36:48,943 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '2a139a55' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1190200a
2019-06-10 14:36:48,943 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,944 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=StatusLogger'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,944 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=ContextSelector'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,945 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Loggers,name=*'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,945 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Appenders,name=*'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,946 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,947 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,947 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2019-06-10 14:36:48,948 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55
2019-06-10 14:36:48,950 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=StatusLogger
2019-06-10 14:36:48,952 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=ContextSelector
2019-06-10 14:36:48,953 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Loggers,name=
2019-06-10 14:36:48,954 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Loggers,name=validation
2019-06-10 14:36:48,955 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Appenders,name=Console
2019-06-10 14:36:48,956 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=2a139a55,component=Appenders,name=validation
2019-06-10 14:36:48,958 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,959 main DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,959 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,959 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=2a139a55] at URI .......................\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1190200a) with optional ClassLoader: null
2019-06-10 14:36:48,959 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2019-06-10 14:36:48,960 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=2a139a55, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1190200a] started OK.
2019-06-10 14:36:49,189 main DEBUG Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@14bdbc74
2019-06-10 14:36:49,190 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2019-06-10 14:36:49,190 main DEBUG Closing JarURLInputStream sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@5a7fe64f
```

Comment: `log4j2.xml` should not be placed at root of the project. It should be on classpath of the application. If it is Maven project, put it inside `src/main/resources/` directory

Comment: Thanks, I moved it to this location and there is no much of difference (file was created after adding: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`). I got similar effect after adding `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` for previous location.

Comment: so now file is getting created and it contains `validation` logger logs. Right ?

Comment: No, sorry. I should be more precise. File is  created, and it's empty, and `validation` logs are printed in console.

Comment: All 4 lines of logs getting printed on console ?

Comment: Yes. All for lines (with proper `LEVELS`). And `validation` lines have word "validation" in place other have class name.

Comment: And can you change `<Configuration status="warn">` line to `<Configuration status="trace">` . It will generate log4j logs on console, kindly upload the output on your question.

Comment: I added logs as you requested. I didn't know that it's the way to locate log4j2 logs.

Comment: I tried same configuration as yours and it is working as per my expectation. From logs, I got to know that your project is a web project so there may be some other dependencies and this issue might be related to configuration overriding by other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing my configuration. I also suspected that it should work. Whats' interesting, today I got back to project and after restart (PC and Eclipse) it seems to work. Maybe Spring/Log4j2 uses some catching of configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration (in question) was correct.

It all started working fine after restarting computer (and Eclipse IDE). Unfortunately I don't know why, but I'll post this answer for future readers.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem.
I have checked you also have the following line  in your first post:

2019-06-10 14:36:48,959 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=2a139a55] at URI xxxx (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@1190200a) with optional ClassLoader: null

Could this be related with the prolem?
didi you find more details on how you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use multiple appenders for console and file.

Comment: I have two appenders on `Appenders` list and two `Loggers` with different appenders. Could you elaborate on the solution?